# I need to make my UIImageView fit inside my UIScrollView without panning. [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an image inside of an iOS UIScrollView that only takes up about 1/3rd of the total screen space. The image is too large, so the scrollView is allowing panning around the image. I want the image to be small enough so that there is no panning necessary to see the entire image. How do I resize the image to make it fit inside of the scroll view?

This is the code I am using to set up the image view and the scroll view.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the ImageView's size equal to the scrollView's size. And set the imageView's content mode to scale to fill 
Eg:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: This works except for one problem. `self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.size;`is causing the build to fail. The error is "Property 'size' not found on object of type 'UIImageView'".

Comment: self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size; Sorry My bad :) Don't Forget to vote Up :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't not make the frame of imageView as the size of image(since image is too large). Set the frame of imageview as you desired and set image contentmode.

You should probably need to pick right image content mode

```
self.imageView.contentMode = (Pick right content mode you need)

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
    UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
    UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
    UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
};
```